# How do I delete elements from an std::set that is stored inside a std::map?

Tags: c++, iteration, stdmap, stdset

I have the following data structure stored in a class.

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> myMap;
 public:
  void remove(std::string id); //trying to remove items from sets inside myMap
}
```

There is then a method to attempt to delete items from the sets. I tried the following 2 ways but neither worked. Approach 1, use `for` range.

```
for (auto pair : myMap) {
 auto set = pair.second;
 if (set.count(id)) {
  set.erase(id);
 }
}
```

Approach 2, use `iterator`.

```
auto it = myMap.begin();
while (it != myMap.end()) {
 auto set = it->second;
 if (set.count(id)) {
  set.erase(id);
 }
 it++;
}
```

What's the right way of removing elements from the sets inside a map in C++? Note that my code used to work when I had `myMap` defined as `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>*>` (pointers).

Comment: You're making many unnecessary copies...

Comment: You are missing `&` in many places in your code, without this you operate on copy of `set`. `auto& pair : myMap`, `auto& set = pair.second;`.

Comment: Why do you expect that any changes to some variable called `set` will have any impact, whatsoever, on another object that's stored in a map?

Comment: TL;DR: `auto` is not deduced to be reference until you ask explicitly to make that type a reference. Plain `auto` will always create a copy.

Comment: It appears you are simulating a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a `std::map` like this:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> myMap;
myMap["a"].insert("aaa");
myMap["a"].insert("abb");
myMap["a"].insert("acc");

myMap["b"].insert("aaa");
myMap["b"].insert("abb");
myMap["b"].insert("acc");
```

Then you can delete items from `std::set` by doing the following:

```cpp
for (auto& i : myMap) {
    i.second.erase("aaa");
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEJN4AHVAsLraewyaCnt5qdFY29kZOLm6KypiqvgwEzMQE/samnHEqobTJqQThdo7OrrwKKWkZgdmVhcWR0eUAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDM1siGWADU4v066pXEmMxGE9jiAAwAggNDI5jjk0bM7osr65KDtMMGYxM6SgSHa0fWBKN71hAt4wDssmujv6OV6BAID2B0mAKBM2swFI/wIgJANyu4IRBGIUMO/WwzwAngBZfYTb6rP44/EHACsskkkmYUkk4nJABEAHTWJRpCB05jcuktQlHElGPEEylcukMlls5wETnU5gOBy8/k/P5CskMqk08VM1m0dkyrnICTUvn9IkC1XCimaxXUiW6/Wymk8k3K4mW9Wi6m2%2Bk6qUcrkKpVmi2/NUim3ayV66VO5hG4PmlW/ZFoAxPK5XcbUgDyrHQz32IDpOx0WeR5lYbtDoxoxFGEGY6dQozQetukgAbKM8KMQKT9u9xF8ayTUx0M5Ms3hmVQ8MRKqXy3CgZXq8mSbWSA2m0RW3RKlJu3w%2Bz3mUo2%2BghyON5u/uP00vJqMT5nnxXtFWQ7e/sPGTW/yOGs6x3Zsjx7U9w3ca8iTvX4ZwvOh0GZZxmCUOMXUkU1YN/D5/3uDcH0nMt3xXEBKyfHRs0kWxMAAd0Ldxi2pSjYXhNdv3WDcQMbZt93bcDe37KCYNHe8yLTYjp1nedFzfKiP3QL8k3dO8eN3Fs20PLsX1PBCEiQ0SfzvIjWNfKdSPYz83Tgz58NUuygI3WYCE6WhRmWas8J6NpWBAHpyR6UhTB6ZYgtQfyyxkOR/g6LptgGTggoIfywpaNoAGsQHJSRmU7foPmWD5yQ%2BTgAA5lk4clOxqoR/O4IKQrC0gIp6IKFBAZZSBS0KfNIOBYBgRAUFQIx3DwdgyAoCA0DGiaymABRaH2BQEFQAhSDnVgCGcDqIAcVKgocaxUmxfyktIWajC0Agc1oVgzt60gsD2UR2EO575wSNQADdMA6p7MAADwSdNemax5lA%2B1g8AcYhTr0LBzuStEjGRtoaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEYRRBQOQ5CEWGOsgNpUHcPIAYAWjpgEJkZY0qWkTgPna%2BJEg0CBzBqLJSHMRpShcbJgh8OgBaCLxJdoEWojKOpubyApqn0TJBCUXIkiqIprBKRWxcUPXpbqPWFeaTg2gUOLui4Xz/MC4KPtaoGys7OnO24UZgCNBtUQMWgMveCBcEIbdEphPQ5sm7N%2Bmt0YorZ5LDvS0gsoK5lyTqnoGtINHyS6prwv89rOu6tP%2BqGiAkAndx03IShZvGyazHwIhjcxxgWHevG6PhpieiSx2Asa13/MS0Y6MIBBRndz3vd9/2IED4OWlT3r04QOYsBcN5c/zwvi4ntrFArnq0sykBuA%2BZl%2Bk7SQAE43EkMrOCfsruH6fpeD8np%2Bjjyeq1TeV9c6SCAc1EBlct5tD%2BguXwN8gA)

**Why approach from the question is not working?**

Because, by doing the following `for(auto pair : myMap) {...}` and `auto set = pair.second;` you are actually working on the copy of the data from `myMap`. So, instead you need to use references to the actual data like `for(auto& pair : myMap) {...}` and `auto& set = pair.second;`.

Furthermore, [`std::set::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) removes the data from the `std::set` if it **exists** so there is **no** need to manually check for the existence of the id.

Answer (score 1):

You're copying the object you meant to mutate. It seems like you have a Java background. In C++ if you want reference semantics (as opposed to value semantics) you should use references (`auto &` instead of `auto` in this case). Here's how you do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

class MyClass {
 private:
  std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> myMap;

 public:
  void remove(std::string const& id) {
    std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(),
                  [&id](auto& p) { p.second.erase(id); });
  }
};
```